# how to kill the session on stopping of server

Tags: java, jsp, session, tomcat

I have made a project in `java`, `jsp`, `servlets`. I have done the session management on login and logout processes. I am facing a problem here. When I do NOT logout from application and stop my `apache tomcat server` and restart it again, my session does not kill. I want my session to be vanished on stopping of server. Can I do this in some `.xml` configurable files inside `apache tomcat` directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply add/uncomment below line in "%Tomcat_Home%/conf/context.xml"

```
<Manager pathname="" />
```

This will avoid saving sessions on server shutdown.

[Disable Session Persistence](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Persistence_Across_Restarts)

Comment: where is this setting located

Comment: Add/un-comment in "%Tomcat_Home%/conf/context.xml"